# Regex: pairing up numbers and '#'-preceded comments in a list of strings

Tags: python, regex, parsing

So I have some lines of text that are stored in a list as follows:

```
lines = ['1.9 #comment 1.11* 1.5 # another comment',
         '1.23',
         '3.10.3* #commennnnnt 1.2 ']
```

I want to create:

```
[{'1.9': 'comment'},
 {'1.11*': ''},
 {'1.5': 'another comment'},
 {'1.23': ''},
 {'3.10.3*': 'commennnnnt'},
 {'1.2': ''} ]
```

In other words, I want to take the list apart and pair each decimal number with either the comment (starting with '#'; we can assume that no numbers occur in it) that appears right after it on the same line, or with an empty string if there is no comment (e.g., the next thing after it is another number).

Specifically, a 'decimal number' can be a single digit, followed by a dot and then either one or two digits, optionally followed by a dot and one or two more digits. A '*' may appear at the very end. So like this(?): `r'\d\.\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?\*?')`

I've tried a few things with `re.split()` to get started. For example, splitting the first list item on either the crazy decimal regex or `#`, before worrying about the dict pairings:

```
>>> crazy=r'\d\.\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?\*?'

>>> re.split(r'({0})|#'.format(crazy), results[0])
```

Result:

```
[u'',
 u'1.9',
 None,
 u' ',
 None,
 None,
 u'comment ',
 u'1.11',
 None,
 u' ',
 u'1.5',
 None,
 u' ',
 None,
 None,
 u' test comment']
```

This looks like something I can filter and work with, but is there a better way? (also, wow...it seems the parentheses in my crazy regex allow me to keep the decimal number delimiters as desired!)

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work:

```
lines = ['1.9 #comment 1.11* 1.5 # another comment',
         '1.23',
         '3.10.3* #commennnnnt 1.2 ']

entries =  re.findall(r'([0-9.]+\*?)\s+((?:[\# ])?[a-zA-Z ]*)', " ".join(lines))
ldict = [{k: v.strip(" #")} for k,v in entries]

print ldict
```

This displays:

```
[{'1.9': 'comment'}, {'1.11*': ''}, {'1.5': 'another comment'}, {'1.23': ''}, {'3.10.3*': 'commennnnnt'}, {'1.2': ''}]
```